# Module 'Cloud_Firestore' not found - XCode - Flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I was actually searching about this issue and i found many solutions here but after applying all solutions and nothing worked for me i decided to ask,

i did all the development for my flutter app on windows so i moved all the files to mac in order to publish my application to app store.

i have installed VSCode, cocoapods, git and all the necessary tools on mac then i followed the Firebase guide to integrate with the project and did the following:

1- i installed the google-services.plist file and put it under runner folder.

2- i ran `pod init` and created pod file.

3- i have added the dependencies for Firebase in the podFile.

4- i ran `pod install` to install the dependencies.

5- i have installed xcode and opened the "ios" folder only from my flutter project, i made sure that my developer account, identifiers, certificates, provisioning profile and more settings are all set.

6- i hit product > archive and this what happens:

[image]

also if i removed the cloud_firestore it will continuously give the same error on each package.

this is my podFile and VSCode file structures:

[image]

Comment: i followed all the steps mentioned and i still have the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a while i found out the solution and its quite simple, for anyone who trying to archive and upload flutter app to app store and having the issue of not detecting the Firebase modules please follow these steps:

note: if you have been already trying and you have created podFiles or plist files like google-services.plist please remove them all and start over...

1- make sure when you use mac device that you install flutter SDK and all the necessary tools (VSCode, git, Cocoapods) in case you are using it only for deployment.

2- after setting up your mac device for flutter development open your files on VSCode and leave it open.

3- open XCode and select open a project or file and select the `ios` folder, or you can open XCode then return to VSCode and right click (Control + Click) on the `ios` folder and select "open with XCode".

4- go to your Firebase console and open your project, if you have already set-up your project with IOS click on the IOS project and scroll down to find "Download google-services.plist", Otherwise please setup your project for IOS by only installing google-services.plist file and skip the other steps.

5- go to your Downloads or the place that you downloaded the plist file on and drag it to your XCode under the bottom runner folder where your "info" file exist.

6- go to VSCode now and and open the terminal and type `cd ios`.

7- This step is the magic, on your terminal type `flutter pub get`, and you will see an auto podFile generated on your ios folder !.

8- now type `pod install` and congratulations all pods and dependencies for Firebase are installed correctly.

9- Close XCode and re-open it choosing the ios folder you will notice a change on the files structure.

10- from products tap above choose destination to "any ios device" then Archive.

have a good day !

Answer (score 1):

I Have same in my file, but my error are in Xcode : https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjYdC.jpg