# Module 'Cloud_Firestore' not found - XCode

Tags: flutter, xcode, google-cloud-firestore

[enter image description here][1]```
When I try to verify my App with Xcode I get this error

I was actually searching about this issue and i found many solutions here but after applying all solutions and nothing worked for me i decided to ask,

```
I try to follow this module https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73917912/module-cloud-firestore-not-found-xcode-flutter

But not work


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjYdC.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case but not with `cloud_firestore`. In my case my **Podfile**  was all empty except these lines:

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!

end
```

I compared this Podfile to an earlier one I had on my commits and it turns out that somehow project's Podfile was emptied out.
On a separate project I built using `cloud_firestore` the following was my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I check my file and have same, but my error are in my Xcode : https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjYdC.jpg